# Cutting sugar in savory butternut squash dishes

Tags: pasta, soup, squash

In making savory dishes--specifically ravioli or soups, I find the sweetness of the butternut squash to be a little much.  I typically roast the squash with onions, and this only concentrates the sugars.

What are my options for adding something to reduce the (for me) overpowering sweetness of these dishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruth Lively at *Fine Cooking* has [a similar problem](http://www.finecooking.com/article/taming-the-sweetness-of-butternut-squash) and suggests:

> - Orange or lemon juice (or zest) adds brightness and zing. A splash of    vinegar helps, too.
> - Tomatoes, which are both sweet and acidic, make a bridge for    full-flavored squash dishes.
> - Sharp cheeses like Asiago, Parmesan, feta, and goat cheese lend a    salty note and highlight the nutty side of squash’s flavor.
> - Robust herbs, such as sage, rosemary, and thyme, work with the earthy    qualities of the squash, yet still offer an assertive
>     contrast    to    its sweet side, too.
> - Bold spices like cumin, coriander, nutmeg, mace, cinnamon, ginger,    and curry have a natural affinity to squash, making the perfect
>     bridge from earthy to intriguing.

You may also consider substituting a differing squash; Royal Oak Farm Orchard[has a nice guide (pdf) to many squashes](http://www.royaloakfarmorchard.com/pdf/ROF_Squash_Guide.pdf) and includes sweetness among the descriptions.